# Cakephp security component error

Tags: cakephp-3.0

The error is:

'_Token' was not found in request data.

It happens on the redirect at the end of an action

I went through the debug and i can see that its coming from a function called _validToken()

I've no idea why this particular controller is doing this though as i have others that do similar actions and are working perfectly

The action that triggers this does everything it's supposed to right up to the redirect at the end

The problem was not evident until i implemented ssl so it could have been there the whole time waiting to pounce!

I've only just started using the security component and i could really do with a few pointers, so if anyone out there could nudge me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out eventually

It was such a simple problem

I had something like this at the end of my form:

```
<?= 
  $this->Form->button(__('Submit'));
  $this->Form->end() ;
?>
```

It works. It also works when you turn on auth. But it stops working as soon as you load the security component

Change it to this:

```
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And it works with the security component

Silly mistake i suppose but hard to find because it worked fine for most if the development process and then broke when i added the security component!

Comment: This is a pure bug in your PHP. `<?=` will always echo only the first thing in it. So your `end` function call was happening, but the output was discarded instead of being included in your HTML.